# Tapioca shims for Rails Engines?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorbet

I have a Rails application using Rails engines and [packwerk](https://github.com/shopify/packwerk) to organize the code. Each of the packwrk component has an `engine.rb` file, which sometimes looks like this:

```rb
module Foobar
  class Engine < ::Rails::Engine
    isolate_namespace Foobar

    initializer :foobar_set_migration_paths do |app|
      unless app.root.to_s.match? root.to_s
        config.paths['db/migrate'].expanded.each do |expanded_path|
          app.config.paths['db/migrate'] << expanded_path
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I'm also using Sorbet with Tapioca to type my files. I'm trying to bring these `engine.rb` files to `# typed: strict`, but when I do it complain about the `root.to_s` part, saying the method does not exist for `Rails::Engine`, but the suggestions Sorbet give are wrong.

Tapioca allows creating shims to properly type these situations, but I can't find a way to fix it.

How can I fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like replacing `root.to_s` with `config.root.to_s` fixes the issue!

Comment: I'm not so sure why you think you need to cast it into strings. Pathname instances are comparable.